# BitConverter Exception, the destination array is too small

Tags: c#, byte, bitconverter

This is pretty simple to create. I have a simple byte array with proof that it has data in it on runtime : 
[image]

Then I simply do

```
var bytedata = BitConverter.ToUInt32(byte_array,0);
```

It compiles, but I get an `Argument Exception` on runtime that says that the destination array is too small.

From microsoft msdn documentation :

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx

Comment: Can you describe what problem you are trying to solve? Your destination type is 4 bytes long and you are trying to create such a value from only 3 bytes. The MSDN example uses 4 bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of integer (in C#) is 4 bytes. You need at least 4 bytes for the conversion to succeed. The sample shows that there are only 3.

(Not sure why the message says "*destination array*". It is rather "*source*".)

Comment: Thx! About the message, probably a translation error from Microsoft (my visual studio is in french)

Comment: @AntoineLev It is the same "_destination array_" in English :).